# click to return false, click again to return true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When someone clicks a button I want my function to return `false` and the `keydown` function will be disabled.

Then, if I click this same button a second time, it will return `true` and the `keydown` function will be enabled.

I did like this but it only returns `false` and `keydown` function disabled. I also need to enable this `keydown` function by clicking this button.

How can I do this?

```js
var controlsEnabled = true;
$(".keyboard-btn").on('click', function() {
  controlsEnabled = false;
});

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (controlsEnabled) {
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
      verticalSlideDown();
      console.log("pressed key for Down : " + e.keyCode);
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      verticalSlideUp();
      console.log("pressed key for Up: " + e.keyCode);
    }

    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      var div = $(".scroll-inner-container");
      console.log("pressed key for stop : " + e.keyCode);
      div.stop();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="keyboard-btn">click here</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your click even only ever sets controlEnabled to false. You need a way to toggle.

The quickest option is to write this

```
$(".keyboard-btn").on('click', function() {
  controlsEnabled = !controlsEnabled // will toggle false -> true or true -> false;
});
```

You could also use if statements to achieve the same thing.. like this

```
$(".keyboard-btn").on('click', function()
{
      if(controlsEnabled)
      {
          controlsEnabled = false;
      }
      else
      {
          controlsEnabled = true;
      }
});
```

This is more long-winded, but perfectly valid, and you could argue it's easier to read. You could also use a ternary operator like this

```
controlsEnabled = (controlsEnabled)? false : true;
```

But that wouldn't really give any advantage, being neither easier to read, or more elegant. But it's worth knowing the different ways to conditionally set a value based on itself. You never know when it might come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$(".keyboard-btn").on('click', function() {
  controlsEnabled = !controlsEnabled;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. (!controlsEnabled) is this return false value..?

Comment: Well, it alternates between true and false, in programming, the `!` sign means `not`, so whenever its true, it turns into false, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

This may helpful

```
$(".keyboard-btn").on('click', function () {

       controlsEnabled= controlsEnabled? false :true ; //  controlsEnabled = !controlsEnabled 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace first 4 lines with this code :

```
var controlsEnabled = true;
$(".keyboard-btn").on('click', function() {
  controlsEnabled = !controlsEnabled;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your function doesn't return anything at the moment - you need to add the `return` keyword.

Secondly, your code isn't performing a boolean switch, it is merely assigning a boolean value. As `true=1` and `false=0`, you can write:

```
controlsEnabled^=1;
```

which uses the XOR operator to switch from true to false and back again.